# How to check the information of the polygons form and size of a .shp file other than the attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, qgis

I have this shapefile (https://drive.google.com/file/d/11FQ5GLngTBPLDLekJlL7aiEATkq-En_h/view?usp=sharing) and I am studying the land use cover in some areas in Brazil. There is the classes (between 1 and 6) and it was supposed to have de size of the area (in hectare) in each row corresponding to its class.

For example:

codigo, area, type(tipo)

123,     982,     2

But instead, I've got:

codigo, area, type(tipo)

123,     0,      2

The thing is, when I categorize the shapefile to see the classes on the map, it classifies correctly. But the area value is 0, **how is this possible**?
[Printscreen of the classification of the shapefile in QGIS. Its categories are right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTDQa.png)

The type or "tipo" in portuguese means the shp's class. It wasn't me who did this shapefile archive, it was hand over to me and now I have to obtain this area value and calculate. I had already code in Python to the calculation part, but I cannot do anything if I can't check the area size.

So it occurred to me, is it possible the size area is alocated in another file? And this column in attributes table in QGIS is not important?

(I'm new at GIS in general)

[The attribute table in QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8UR6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your shapefile is saved in a geographic CRS (`EPSG:4674`), thus units are in degrees.  Like this, you won't get correct measurements. Reproject the layer to a projected CRS but be aware that it is one that is apt to calculate areas, e.g. local UTM zone.

By the way: questions regarding GIS are better asked at https://gis.stackexchange.com/